# Add extra dots but line should pass through the recent data point in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am trying to generate the above fig with following code, i am representing two lines, for suppose in a line there are multiple data points on the same day, then all points should be plotted and the line should only pass through the most recent data point.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


xpoints = ['day'+str(i) for i in range(1,31)]
line1 = random.sample(range(100, 140), 30)
line2 = random.sample(range(60, 100), 30)

line3 = random.sample(range(100, 140), 30)
line4 = random.sample(range(60, 100), 30)


fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(xpoints, line1)
plt.plot(xpoints, line2)

plt.scatter(xpoints, ['', '', '', '', '', 124, 112, 133, 121, 104, 119, 120, 139, 114, 128, 132, 113,
                      '', '', '', '', 136, 100, 103, 108,'' ,'', 106, '', ''])
plt.scatter(xpoints, line4)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

When i try to use Scatter to display multiple data points on the same day, getting above error, any help much appriciate.

Comment: What do you mean by  "recent data point". Can you please explain the problem so that others understand it and where are you stuck ?

Comment: @mujjiga A day has multiple values generates based on time, for suppose [100, 101, 110, 123]. In between taking recent value '123' and passing that line through that point, But i should have to display the 100, 101, 110 per day as dots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pandas dataframe with the empty strings filled with np.nan to plot the points the create a new column with the points for the line (if I've understood your question correctly)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"day":xpoints,"val":['', '', '', '', '', 124, 112, 133, 121, 104, 119, 120, 139, 114, 128, 132, 113,
                      '', '', '', '', 136, 100, 103, 108,'' ,'', 106, '', ''],"line4": line4})

df["val"] = df["val"].replace("",np.nan)

df['line5'] = df["val"].fillna(df["line4"])

plt.scatter(df["day"],y=df["val"])

plt.scatter(xpoints, line4)

plt.plot(xpoints,df["line5"])

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for everything, i just replace the empty values with nan, its work great